# Neatly Display .pkl file in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I'm struggling to neatly display .pkl file in Python 3

The entire github repository is here, https://github.com/udacity/ud120-projects

Entire Enron Dataset (I'm unsure if it's required, but I'm including since I no longer see it in github), https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz

Here is /datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py

```
import pickle

enron_data = pickle.load(open("../final_project/final_project_dataset.pkl", "rb"))
```

when I add

```
print(enron_data)
```

I get following messy (truncated) output. Please tell how to organize.

```
E:\ud120-projects-master\ud120-projects-master\datasets_questions>python explore_enron_data.py
{'METTS MARK': {'salary': 365788, 'to_messages': 807, 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 1061827, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'bonus': 600000, 'email_address': 'mark.metts@enron.com', 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': 'NaN', 'total_stock_value': 585062, 'expenses': 94299, 'from_poi_to_this_person': 38, 'exercised_stock_options': 'NaN', 'from_messages': 29, 'other': 1740, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 1, 'poi': False, 'long_term_incentive': 'NaN', 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 702, 'restricted_stock': 585062, 'director_fees': 'NaN'}, 'BAXTER JOHN C': {'salary': 267102, 'to_messages': 'NaN', 'deferral_payments': 1295738, 'total_payments': 5634343, 'loan_advances': 'NaN', 'bonus': 1200000, 'email_address': 'NaN', 'restricted_stock_deferred': 'NaN', 'deferred_income': -1386055, 'total_stock_value': 10623258, 'expenses': 11200, 'from_poi_to_this_person': 'NaN', 'exercised_stock_options': 6680544, 'from_messages': 'NaN', 'other': 2660303, 'from_this_person_to_poi': 'NaN', 'poi': False, 'long_term_incentive': 1586055, 'shared_receipt_with_poi': 'NaN', 'restricted_stock': 3942714, 'director_fees': 'NaN'}, 'ELLIOTT STEVEN': {'salary': 170941, 'to_messages': 'NaN', 'deferral_payments': 'NaN', 'total_payments': 211725, 'loan_advances':
```

Comment: look online for prettyprint libraries

Comment: Thank you @TasosPapastylianou